# Why absolute value when going from $P((X-μ)^2\geq t^2 \sigma^2)$ to $P(\vert X-μ\vert \geq t\sigma)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Ex 3.6.2 in Casella and Berger has
$$
P(\frac{(X-μ)^2}{\sigma^2}\geq t^2) \leq \frac{1}{t^2} 
$$
Then, "doing some obvious algebra" they state
$$
P(\vert X-μ\vert \geq t\sigma)\leq \frac{1}{t^2}
$$
Now, it is clear they multiplied by $\sigma^2$ and took a square root.

> But why is putting the $X-μ$ in absolute value correct? (i.e., why can we rigorously do this)

I get that there are positive and negative square roots, and that's likely why we need the absolute value (i.e. the squared term includes some positive and some negative values of $X$). But, **formally**, why is it correct to go from $\sqrt{(X-\mu)^2}\geq t\sigma^2$ to $\vert X-μ\vert \geq t\sigma$

Comment: Simply because $(X - \mu)^2 \geq t^2$ iff $|X-\mu| \geq t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in general, true that
$$
A^2\geq B^2\iff |A|\geq |B|
$$
for instance as a consequence of $\sqrt{C^2}=|C|$. In this case, it seems that $t\sigma$ is always positive, so the absolute value around that term is superfluous and has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Prove this set equality:

$$\{|X-\mu|>t\sigma\}=\{(X-\mu)^2>t^2\sigma^2\}$$